# ASP.net gridview evaluating datafield after each record

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hey all i am wondering if it was possible to evaluate the datafield each time it places a new record into a row?

my gridview code is this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlGrid" runat="server">
    <div class="left_main_container" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat="server" CssClass="GridViewStyle"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" Width="100%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="theName" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" />
            </Columns>
            <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
            <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyRowStyle" />
            <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />
            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
            <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

The field i need to evaluate is status. I need to find out if the status is **yes** or if its **no**. If its **no** then i need to make it a link for the user to be able to change it to a **yes**.

The gridview is populated by this code:

```
    Dim objConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim objCmd As MySqlCommand

    objConn = New MySqlConnection(strConnString)
    objConn.Open()

    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT id, status, " & _
                "CONCAT(' ', first_name, last_name) AS theName " & _
             "FROM(builder_requests) " & _
             "ORDER BY status, id DESC;"

    Dim dtReader As MySqlDataReader
    objCmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, objConn)
    dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader()

    grdView.DataSource = dtReader
    grdView.DataBind()

    dtReader.Close()
    dtReader = Nothing

    objConn.Close()
    objConn = Nothing
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Try using **RowDataBound** event, Read More : **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use a TemplateField and a function in your code-behind to do this sort of thing.

I am assuming your status field is a string field not boolean but if not let me know and I can adjust the example.

Replace your `BoundField` with...

Markup:

```
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("status")%>&nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdChangeStatus" runat="server" CommandName="ChangeStatusToYes" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'
                    Visible='<%# SetChangeStatusVisibility(Eval("status")) %>'>Change to Yes</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And add code behind function...

Code:

```
Protected Function SetChangeStatusVisibility(status As Object) As String
    Dim strStatus As String = status.ToString()
    If strStatus = "no" Then
        Return "True"
    Else
        Return "False"
    End If
End Function
```

Then you can handle the `GridView.RowCommand` event to change the status value based on the id value in CommandArgument :)